# Filtering in FlexDashboard. The filtering options are not a part of the dataset

Tags: r, flexdashboard

I have a Flexdashboard code that is running perfectly fine. But I have a filter option here at the side. Once I click on "Month" I should see the plots. But currently what is happening is that as soon as open the app the plots are displayed(this should not happen). But the thing here is the filtering option is not a part of dataset

````
---
title: "Untitled"
source_code: embed
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard: null
  orientation: rows
vertical_layout:
  runtime: shiny
---

```{r global, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(flexdashboard)
df <- structure(list(A = structure(c(1L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 
                                     5L, 5L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 7L, 2L), .Label = c("asd", "dfg", "fgdsgd", 
                                                                             "fsd", "gdfgd", "gs", "sdfg", "sf"), class = "factor"), B = c(29L, 
                                                                                                                                           24L, 46L, 50L, 43L, 29L, 32L, 24L, 35L, 39L, 33L, 47L, 53L, 26L, 
                                                                                                                                           31L), C = structure(c(8L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 
                                                                                                                                                                 2L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 4L), .Label = c("asd", "er", "fg", "gf", "gfd", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "gfg", "qw", "sf", "tr"), class = "factor"), D = c(36L, 56L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    39L, 26L, 56L, 35L, 27L, 31L, 33L, 45L, 34L, 27L, 43L, 40L, 56L
                                                                                                                                                                                                 ), E = structure(c(9L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 10L, 8L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                    10L, 9L, 9L, 5L), .Label = c("er", "fg", "g", "gd", "gf", "gfg", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "gtd", "qw", "sf", "tr"), class = "factor"), F = c(44L, 34L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    37L, 23L, 37L, 51L, 28L, 36L, 33L, 31L, 39L, 43L, 25L, 37L, 43L
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ), num = 1:15), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Summary {data-width=650}
==========

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                Month/Day {.sidebar}
-------------------
```{r}
selectInput("Interval","Intervals",choices =                      
              c("","Day","Month","Weekly","Hourly"))
```

Row
----------

### B Value

```{r}
gauge(paste(sum(df$B)),min = 0,max = 1000)
```

### D Value

```{r}
gauge(paste(sum(df$D)),min = 0,max = 1000)
```
````

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If the filtering variable `Day,Weekly,Hourly` is not part of the dataset how are we supposed to filter the dataset?

Comment: Like If i select "Month" I need the gauges to be displayed? if Not nothing should be displayed. If you run this code, you might get some idea

Comment: A gage displays a particular value. currently it is set to display df$B and df$D. These do not depend on Interval.

Comment: Let me explain. The filtering (Day, Month, Weekly, Hourly) is different and data set is different. I can say this way. This dataset is a monthly dataset and similarly I have another dataset that is hourly. But as of now this dataset is monthly. It is just a filtering option that is it. Once I click on Month, the gauges should be displayed. Hope you got my point

Comment: You should include this other data in the example above.